Adding comment in WKT file
Let's say we want to add a comment in between some of the WKT lines here,
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(4 6), LINESTRING(4 6, 7 10))
POINT ZM (1 1 5 60) ***COMMENT GOES HERE***
POINT M (1 1 80)

What is the syntax for adding a comment?
I looked up some standards, but it seems all they do is describe the syntax of each item, not the spaces between items.
So maybe too bad, perhaps comments depend on what file one puts the WKT strings into. If I put them into an XML file, then use XML comment syntax. If I put them into a SQL file, then use SQL comment syntax, etc.
So maybe there is no "WKT file", just "WKT strings."

How do you parse/use your WKT data, in plain text or in JSON structures?

I see. So a "real WKT comment" would go POINT(11 HERE 44) so would not be worth defining.

To validate your WKT check this https://www.here.com/learn/blog/wkt-well-known-text-format-with-hereapis in the section How can I validate WKT is properly formatted?

Actually it would be nice to be able to add comments: LINESTRING(0 0 SW corner, 0 1 NW corner,...)

I guess I had better just get used to the fact that just as not all restaurants have washrooms, one cannot expect to always be able to "find a handy rest area along the freeway" "to leave a comment."
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961006/can-a-csv-file-have-a-comment . (So one must practice "holding it in", and "keep your comments to yourself", or "put them in a separate file". Or pre-process your file to remove the comments before handing it to the next step in the pipe.)

WKT as defined by the OGC is neither a file format (like CSV) nor a full format ontology (like JSON); it is a standardized encoding of geometric Simple Features into a (human readable) text representation. Consider this a type standard, and much like you cannot comment (the text representation of) a float type by default you cannot comment WKT by default - except, of course, you develop or find a serializer that implements it (like '3 ***decimal point*** 14 ***But this ain't PI, John!***').

I get it. Sort of like there are rules for what is a proper sentence in English. But how one juxtaposes said sentences is a different matter.

＠t.ry perhaps you might turn your comment into the official answer.
